# What does this command does? env |> temp.conf awk

Tags: bash

I've searched all over the web but cannot find how this command works (maybe because I don't know what words to use), specially  this part `|>`

I know about pipes and redirections but I've never seen it used togheter.

```
env|>${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}/httpd_temp.conf awk 'BEGIN{FS="="} $1 ~ /^OPENSHIFT/ {print "PassEnv", $1}'
```

Comment: Did you check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45201/bash-what-does-do ?

Comment: @RahulTripathi: How is that relevant? That question's about `>|`, whereas this one's about `|>`.

Comment: How did you find that question? I literally put `|>` in the search box here and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|>` doesn't have any special meaning.

Bash lets you put redirections before even the first word of a simple command; so your command is actually equivalent to

```
env | awk  ... > ${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}/httpd_temp.conf
```

(But I have no clue why someone would write it the way you posted.)

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the exceptions are.

Comment: @chepner: I don't have an authoritative list, I just know from experience that this only seems to work for simple commands, not compound commands. For example, `> foo ( bar )` and `> foo { bar ; }` and `> foo while bar ; do baz ; done` are all syntax errors, even though the same commands work fine if you move the redirection to the end.

Comment: Oh, right. This is documented in the `bash` man page (and probably in the POSIX spec somewhere): "The following redirection operators  may  precede  or  **appear  anywhere**  within a **simple** command or may follow a command." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @chepner: Ah, thanks! Somehow I've never managed to see that; I always skimmed the wrong part, I guess. I'll update the answer to make it more precise.